# Chef: run two recipes with different users in same cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I have a Chef cookbook that needs to call two recipes: one as `root`, that will create a new user and add it to `/etc/sudoers`, and another recipe which is supposed to run using the newly created user.

I understand I can easily execute commands as a certain user using the `bash` resource, but in this case I need to call `include_recipe` in both cases (root and new user).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chef-client runs as `root`user and you cannot simply run a recipe as another user.

It is completely legitimate to create a user and then do couple of things in the name of this user, e.g:

```rb
user "foo"

directory "/usr/local/foo" do
  owner "foo"
end

execute "install foo" do
  command "whatever-foo"
  user "foo"
end
```

However, if you have a recipe that you really want to include two times and that should really do the exact same things, just for different users (e.g. in their home directory), then forget the idea that *recipes* are everything. Use a [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) that has a `user` property.

Then, you can call this resource two times, once for every user:

```rb
%w{root otheruser}.each do |u|
  mycookbook_myresource "do-it-for-user-#{u}" do
    user u
  end
end
```